# Double values are truncated (rounded) in Virtuoso SRARQL results

Tags: sparql, virtuoso, linked-data, rounding

I am using Virtuoso Opensource 7.2.4 and have a dataset which consists of some data, for example:

```
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
@prefix geo: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#> .
@prefix ap: <http://vocab.linkeddata.es/datosabiertos/def/urbanismo-infraestructuras/alumbrado-publico#> .


<http://linkeddata.es/resource/farolas/lapalma/0> a ap:PuntoDeAlumbrado ;
    geo:long "-17.774237421604201614"^^xsd:double ;
    geo:lat "28.60580329136699973"^^xsd:double .
```

and if I do the following simple SPARQL query

```
PREFIX geo: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#> 
PREFIX ap: <http://vocab.linkeddata.es/datosabiertos/def/urbanismo-infraestructuras/alumbrado-publico#> 
select ?farola ?lat ?long where {
 ?farola a ap:PuntoDeAlumbrado; geo:lat ?lat; geo:long ?long .
}
```

I get the following results. Note that **the values of latitude and longitude are rounded to a less precise value**.

```
+-------------------------------------------------+----------+----------+
|                     farola                      |   lat    |   long   |
+-------------------------------------------------+----------+----------+
| http://linkeddata.es/resource/farolas/lapalma/0 |  28.6058 | -17.7742 |
+-------------------------------------------------+----------+----------+
```

This happens when I set the result format to HTML, XML, JSON, etc. If I ask for results in Turtle, I can the results with the correct precision.

```
@prefix res: <http://www.w3.org/2005/sparql-results#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
_:_ a res:ResultSet .
_:_ res:resultVariable "farola" , "lat" , "long" .
@prefix xsd:    <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
_:_ res:solution [
      res:binding [ res:variable "farola" ; res:value <http://linkeddata.es/resource/farolas/lapalma/0> ] ;
      res:binding [ res:variable "lat" ; res:value 28.60580329136699973 ] ;
      res:binding [ res:variable "long" ; res:value -17.774237421604201614 ] ] .
```

The problem is when I query using Apache Jena [v3.1.0], I get the rounded results. I guess, it asks for application/sparql-results+json as the first preference. What is the best way to make Virtuoso return the non-truncated  values in the result (configuring either Virtuoso or Jena)?

This behavior is the same in the DBpedia SPARQL endpoint as it can be seen in the [HTML Result](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=prefix%20geo%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2003%2F01%2Fgeo%2Fwgs84_pos%23%3E%20%0D%0A%0D%0Aselect%20%3Flat%20%3Flong%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FLiberty_Tower_%28Manhattan%29%3E%20%20geo%3Along%20%3Flong%3B%20geo%3Alat%20%3Flat%20.%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on) vs the [Turtle Result](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=prefix%20geo%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2003%2F01%2Fgeo%2Fwgs84_pos%23%3E%20%0D%0A%0D%0Aselect%20%3Flat%20%3Flong%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FLiberty_Tower_%28Manhattan%29%3E%20%20geo%3Along%20%3Flong%3B%20geo%3Alat%20%3Flat%20.%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fturtle&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on) for the query

```
prefix geo: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#> 
select ?lat ?long where {
 <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Liberty_Tower_(Manhattan)>  geo:long ?long; geo:lat ?lat .
}
```

Comment: `org.apache.jena.sparql.engine.http.QueryEngineHttp::setSelectContentType("TURTLE")`

Comment: Thanks! Apparently only "application/sparql-results+xml", "application/sparql-results+json", "text/tab-separated-values",  "text/csv" are the standard result formats defined in SPARQL 1.1. It is not possible to send other types as Jena does a check for valid formats (and even if it doesn't, it won't know how to parse them). I wonder if this can be fixed in the server side in Virtuoso.

Comment: TSV should work - it is lossless as a SPARQL result format. It is Turtle terms written as one line per result row making it, in effect, "Turtle results".

Comment: Ok, I missed that. In that case `WebContent.contentTypeTextTSV`.

Comment: Thanks @AndyS AKSW. I tried but Jena fails to parse the response from Virtuoso with a ResultSetException: TSV Results malformed, not a variable: "farola". Code snippet: http://pastebin.com/raw/JgM0f53e Exception: http://pastebin.com/raw/eKut5Gwp TSV: http://pastebin.com/raw/cgqQ5xxi

Comment: Anyways, it seems Virtuoso still rounds up the values in TSV even though it is a lossless result format :(

Comment: Are the values actually rounded, or are they just printed that way in the results table?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor that's how the server send them (not just the HTML view). I get the same results using Jena as a client.

Comment: Oh dear - the TSV output is not right for SPARQL results.

Comment: Virtuoso-specific questions, especially where they may herald a bug (as appears possible here), are often best raised to Virtuoso-specific areas such as the [Open Source Project Issues Page](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/), the [Virtuoso Users mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/virtuoso-users/), or the [OpenLink Support Forums](http://boards.openlinksw.com/support/index.php). (ObDisclaimer: I work for [OpenLink Software](http://www.openlinksw.com/), producer of [Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/).)

Comment: Thanks @TallTed I actually posted in the user list but didn't get any reply https://sourceforge.net/p/virtuoso/mailman/message/35107930/ . I will report it as a bug.

Answer (score 3):

As a workaround, you can convert values to strings in the query:

```
prefix geo: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#> 
select (str(?lat) as ?lat) (str(?long) as ?long) where {
  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Liberty_Tower_(Manhattan)>  geo:long ?long; geo:lat ?lat .
}
```

Comment: Hello, If I want to return it as _double_ I have seen that when I type something like ```(DOUBLE(?moment) AS ?mm)``` it returns an error... Same goes if I try ```DECIMAL```, ```FLOOR```.

Answer (score 1):

This is currently being investigated as [Issue#1006](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/1006) on the [GitHub project](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource). As noted there, full values are known to be stored in the database; the truncation issue is seen with some (but not all) output data formats (e.g., `text/turtle` shows no truncation).

We'll update this answer when the issue is resolved.

Comment: according to [Issue#1006](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/1006) the problem has been resolved in version 7.2.7